# SVN - Find changed files with certain name within a certain period

Tags: svn

I'm struggeling to find a svn command that lists all modified files that contains a certain name (e.g. all panels: `*panel*.java`) within a certain period (e.g. from *12/01/2015* to *12/31/2015*).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to find all files that were modified/added/deleted in that period, or all files that exist in the repository in that period?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I mean all *modified* files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all modified files that have a certain name and were modified in a certain date range, use these parameters to the `svn log` subcommand:

```
svn log -r {2015-12-01}:{2015-12-31} -v --search *panel*.java
```

The `-r` (revision range) argument [can take dates](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.revision) in [curly braces](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates), and the `--search` argument [will match file names](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.dates), but only if `-v` (verbose) is passed.